# Matrix multiplication dimensons

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a (n x 3) vector:

```
v = [v1,   [[x,y,z],
    v2,   = [x,y,z],
    vn].    [x,y,z]]
```

And a (n x 3 x 3) matrix:

```
M = [M1,
     M2,
     Mn]
```

The result should be:

```
w = [M1 x v1,
     M2 x v2,
     Mn x vn]
```

So in summary I want to matrix multiply a vector v of shape (n x 3) with a matrix of shape (n x 3 x 3) to get a vector (n x 3).

I can't get the hang of the dimensions so the matrix multiplication will work out as I want.
Help would be appreciated.

PS: I'm using Python with numpy but although I also would appreciate the finished numpy implementation, I guess when I know how to manipulate the dimensions I can implement it in nupy myself.

I also would like to use pure matrix multiplication and no looping

Comment: Please correct your code. [Minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be useful. I'm not able to parse your first code snippet.

Comment: Well of course you aren't as I'm not asking for a specific problem but a general problem of how I can correctly matrix multiply a (nx3x3) with a (nx3) vector. The 'code snippets' are just to illustrate the vector and matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcast:

```
ret = (M @ v[...,None]).reshape(v.shape)

### check
loop = np.array([M[i] @ v[i] for i in range(n)])
(ret==loop).all()
# True
```

Comment: Works and bonus point for providing a proof!

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it exactly the way you'd write with indices?

```
w = np.einsum('kij,kj->ki', M, v)
```

This is equivalent to *w<sub>ki</sub> = M<sub>kij</sub>v<sub>kj</sub>*.

Comment: Because I didn't know that numpy command existed. Thx for introducing it to me

Comment: The command can do wonders. Check the docs.